# isAuthenticated and isAnonymous are returning false simultaneously

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my current spring project, I had a view with this html code:

```
<th:block sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
  <h2 sec:authentication="name"></h2>
</th:block>
<th:block sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
  <p> <a th:href="@{/loginPage}">Login</a> </p>
  <p>
    <ul>
      <li> <a th:href="@{/homeFacebook}">Connect to Facebook</a> </li>
      <li> <a th:href="@{/homeTwitter}">Connect to Twitter</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</th:block>
```

which when I run the application, nothing is being displayed in the page, because the conditionals `sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"` and `sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"` are both returnin false;

My configuration:

**At my Application.java class**

```
  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine  =  new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.addDialect( new SpringSecurityDialect() );
    return engine;
  }
```

**At my pom.xml file**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have other projects whit similar configuration working fine, but in this one i stuck this issue. Someone can see what's wrong here?

**update**

I change the pom.xml to this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
```

and now instead of show nothing, both blocks are being displayed. (if i remove `thymeleaf-spring3` from list of dependencies in the pom.xml file, the page display none of the blocks, like before)

**update 2**

with this code, the page display nothing:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

with that one display both blocks:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
```

but `sec:authentication` is not processed.

Comment: You are mixing thyme leaf  2 and 3 classes that isn't going to work. Also Spirng doesn't support thyme leaf 3 yet. Another thing why are you conigurating thyme leaf yourself. Spring Boot already does that for you, so you can simply remove the bean definition for the `SpringTemplateEngine`.

Comment: Like I said, I have the exactly same dependencies in another project and it's working. Also, I remove the bean definiton for `SpringTemplateEngine` and got the same result.

Comment: I doubt you have the same dependencies especially version wise. Also `spring3` spring boot uses `spring4`. at least your dependencies, from a spring boot perspective are a mess. Just remove the `thymeleaf-spring3` dependency and remove the `version` tag from the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` dependency. Spring Boot manages the versions for you.

Comment: yes, i am sure that i had the same dependencies (it's this project: https://github.com/klebermo/mystore). but i try follow your instructions, and remove `thymeleaf-spring3` and the version tag for `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4`, and now instead of show nothing, both blocks are being displayed (see the update)

Comment: I said remove them not adding a version tag... You haven't followed the instructions. But I'm going to reiterate again that spring doesn't support thyme leaf 3 yet, so adding those dependencies will add nothing but additional classes and probably not processing of the thyme leaf tags. So as mentioned remove the depdnecnies and the specific version tag for the dialect.